# Is it possible to read the values of multiCapabilities on beforeEach?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to launch several proxies corresponding to the port value of `multiCapabilities`. For example, if the `_conf.js` file has two `multiCapabilities` sets, then two proxies should be launched with different port values.

In `_conf.js`, I set the below information:

```
exports.config = {
...
multiCapabilities: [
{ 'browserName': 'chrome',
'proxy': { 'httpProxy': 'localhost:8889' },
'count': '1' },
{ 'browserName': 'firefox',
'proxy': { 'httpProxy': 'localhost:9001' },
'count': '1' },
```

Expectation : Two instances, one whose browser is chrome has a proxy with port `8889`. The other has Firefox as its browser and a proxy with port `9001`.

For this, I tried to use `browser.getProcessedConfig().then(` at beforeEach function in the `spec.js` file. However, I can't get values before launching proxies.

In the `_spec.js` file I am trying to read the `httpProxy` value before launching proxies in this way.

```
var Proxy = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy;

describe('stress testing-' + dateone.curdate2Sec, function() {
var curport = 0;
beforeEach(function (done) {
// READ HTTPPROXY TO PASS AS A PORT NUMBER FOR PROXY
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) { 
curport = config.capabilities.proxy.httpProxy.split(':')[1];
});

/*  Proxy Part */       
var proxy = new Proxy();
return Q.ninvoke(proxy, 'start', curport) 
    .then(
        function (data) {
            console.log('data', data);
            console.log('arguments', arguments);
            browser.params.proxy = proxy;
            browser.params.proxyData = data;
            return data;
        }, 
        function () {
            console.log('start failed');
        })
    .then(
        function() {
            browser.params.proxy.startHAR(browser.params.proxyData.port, 'test', done);
        }
    );
});
```

The protractor instance runs `return Q.ninvoke(proxy, 'start', curport)` first, then resolves `getProcessedConfig`, which happens after launching proxies.

I tried to insert `/* Proxy Part */` into `browser.getProcessedConfig().then(...)`, but it still does not work.

Is there any way that I can read the specific value of `multiCapabilities` immediately on `beforeEach` instead of waiting for the `by .then()`?

This is the main [reference I used](https://github.com/afternoon/protractor-browsermob-test).

Comment: I think that you need to combine promise, which you get by from calling `getProcessedConfig()` and only when it resolves - create a proxy. After that - return a resulting promise from beforeEach, so Protractor will wait for all the sequence of operations.

Comment: @NathanielFord Thanks for your help, Nathaniel Ford!

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Thanks for your suggestion, Michael Radionov!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're close, you can pass `curport` from the Promise to the proxy function with a `.then()` to create a proxy with the right port number. If you find that the rest of the script is not waiting for the proxy to be created, you can execute it within the context of the controlFlow like:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
        return config.capabilities.proxy.httpProxy.split(':')[1];
    }).then(function(curport) {
        browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
            /*  Proxy Part */
            Q.ninvoke(proxy, 'start', curport)
            ... 
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks martin770 for your answer! It is working well now. What I missed was browser.controlFlow().execute() in second .then()!!

Comment: Yeah... we discovered when using protractor with asynchronous calls, you really have to understand the controlFlow for order of execution. Most of the protractor functions (click, getText, etc) already know to insert themselves into the controlFlow which makes them synchronous activities one after the other. When you define an asynchronous call or promise, javascript will attempt to execute it right away asynchronously. But if you wrap it with controlFlow, you can defer the execution of that command until the right moment, and make sure it completes before moving to the next step.

Comment: Yes, that was the most complicated part, since this is the first time using asynchronous language. Thanks!